# Нужно сделать фигуры 10-угольной звезды в CSS

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать фигуры 10-угольной звезды в CSS/HTML

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `clip-path` в помощь https://www.cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/

Answer (score 1):

К примеру, используя SVG можно так сделать:

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="250" height="250">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="450">
      <image xlink:href="http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/daisy-grass-repeating-background.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="450"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g id="layer" transform="translate(932.5364,54.07696)">
    <path  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill:url(#img);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" d="m -755.71429,139.50504 -12.9691,47.17829 -37.72502,-31.15783 -38.22292,30.54499 -12.20607,-47.38143 -48.87689,2.24455 17.97519,-45.50693 -40.86155,-26.913233 41.29054,-26.250331 -17.23849,-45.7910798 48.8343,3.03300547 12.9691,-47.17828967 37.72502,31.157837 38.22292,-30.544997 12.20607,47.38143418 48.87689,-2.24455348 -17.97519,45.5069333 40.86155,26.913233 -41.29054,26.250332 17.23849,45.791079 z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```